# JSF : Reset After Validation=ok

Tags: jsf

im new in JSF,
im using rich:validator for my inputText, and im using type="reset" to clear forms after button click.
so the problem is, even when ther's a validation error , i lose what i just wrote at inputText,
how can we make action of reset AFTER validation success ?
tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stay away from the `type=reset` on the buttons.

I've had times when it does not reset all components correctly. I would just reset the fields in your backing bean as one of the last things you do.

Comment: Note that `<input type="reset">` resets all changed values to *initial values*. It does not clear all values out. So if the initial value is not empty/blank and you actually want to clear out it, then the `<input type="reset">` is the wrong tool. By the way, how did you decipher what the OP is really asking?

Comment: @BalusC I actually tried resetting pages this way back in v1.1, but quickly found out that its just better to write your own reset logic.

Comment: Common misconception among starters is that they think that `<input type="reset">` clears the form with all blank values. It doesn't do that. It resets the form to the initial values, exactly those values as the form was displayed with upon initial request.